# Error while debugging testcases with mockito

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, mockito

I am using Mockito for JUnit, while launching test cases in debug mode it shows popup saying "Unable to insert break points". I tried by changing compiler settings as mentioned in other similar posts, but didn't find any success.
[image]

Comment: May be due to number of test cases in a single file.

Comment: I get this too - I always just click "Don't tell me again" and ignore it - my breakpoints still get hit. This seems to always happen to me in Eclipse with proxy classes...